# Why does download pdf using browser require login while using postman does not?

Tags: c#, api, pdf, postman, content-disposition

I tried to test my APIs (Direct Download Pdf API) using postman (Send & Download) and **all went well and the file was downloaded successfully, no need to set login information**. But when i tried to **use mozilla browser**, it's tell me **login required? why?**

**Here is my response header using postman:**

[image]

**And here when i try using browser, show idm downloader ask username password:** 

[image]

[image]

Here is my code

```
            [Authorize]                
            [HttpGet]
            public IHttpActionResult GetDownloadPdf(string date)
            {
                HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
                ResponseData responseData = new ResponseData();

                try
                {
                    _logDataBLL.SaveRequestLogRecord(RequestType.GET, MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name);

                    MA_MS_Agent objdata = new MA_MS_Agent();

                    //Update - Checking current user still active 
                    var identity = User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
                    if (LoginBLL.isStillActive(identity) == false)
                    {
                        dynamic Reject = new ExpandoObject();
                        Reject.Message = "Authorization has been denied for this request.";

                        return Content(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, Reject);
                    }


                    date = "01" + date.Substring(2);
                    string filename = "1000007"+ "_" + date + ".pdf";

                    ByteArrayContent pdfByte;

                    MA_MS_ApplicationParameter Selected_Parameter = AddReferralBLL.getAppParameterByCode("APPP025");
                    string param_value = Selected_Parameter.ApplicationParameter_Value;

                    string pdfFilePath = param_value + filename;
                    byte[] bytes = null;

                    if (File.Exists(pdfFilePath))
                    {
                       bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(pdfFilePath);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                       return BadRequest();
                    }


                    using (var m = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                       pdfByte = new ByteArrayContent(bytes);
                    }


                    if (pdfByte == null)
                    {
                        responseData = _responseDataBLL.GenerateResponseData(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
                        responseData.status = true;
                        return Ok(responseData);
                    }

                    response.Content = pdfByte;
                    response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
                    response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = filename;
                    response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("Application/pdf");
                    //response.Headers.Add("MyHeader", "MyHeaderValue");
                    //response.Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                    return ResponseMessage(response);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    string error = ex.Message;

                    if (ex.InnerException != null)
                        error += " => " + ex.InnerException.Message;

                    responseData = _responseDataBLL.GenerateResponseData(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, error);

                    _logDataBLL.SaveResponseLogRecord(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(responseData));

                    return Content(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, responseData);
                }

            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Oauth2 Flow:
When you try to access your api from a browser, like your Mozilla browser, you need to get the access token from your oauth server first. So your clientapp should authorize the user and use the users token for the authorisation.

Getting the authtoken depends from your Auth Server.

The keycloak project explains how you can authorize in a JS-ClientApplication like an angular or react app and pass the bearer token to another api.

https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/index.html#_javascript_adapter

Without Authorisation:

you are forcing authorization in your code.
You should replace the [Authorize] attribute with [AllowAnonymous]

```
[AllowAnonymous]                
 [HttpGet]
            public IHttpActionResult GetDownloadPdf(string date)
            {
//.. code
}
```

Update better link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/simple?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: to be honest, i need authorize header to retrieve user information inside token. and when i try allowanonymous, the login form was dissapear, but my api was hit twice from browser, idon't know where the other one came from

Comment: @Fadly i've updated my awnser. You need to get the bearer token in your client app as you do in postman and send it in the header.

Comment: thanks for the advice but i've already try set the bearer and currently facing another issue, my APIs always get called twice when being hit by browser or webview where 2nd request not send the bearer, obviously not because cross origin. but being hit by postman work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your URL requires a basic auth.
It is working in postman because you are sending an `Authorization` header in postman. But in the browser, when you try to open that URL, it doesn't have any authorization header.

Comment: no, i use extension "modify header value" on mozilla browser, so i can access APIs with custome header, and when i try to debug api, the auth header was delivered perfectly from browser